# Zoom Html Mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive

I made a website which works great, both on mobile and desktop, but the problem is that on the mobile version
the screen is too de-zoomed.

Is there any way to zoom it automatically?

I'm attaching 2 photos so you can see how I would like it to zoom in automatically

[screenshot 1: Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfwCK.png)

[screenshot 2: Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yFgQ.png)

Comment: Please add your code, not images.

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). The code in your second second screenshot is unreadable (aside from that, there are many reasons to not post images of code or any other text)

Comment: @DavidMakogon The code shown in the 2nd screenshot is just a placeholder image and has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 1):

try to include

```
<head>
...
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

to your HTML code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).